# Proton as superposition of hadrons: $\vert p\rangle = c_0\vert p_0\rangle+c_1\vert h\rangle+\cdots$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, superposition, multipole-expansion

I have a question regarding hadron fluctuations.

For instance on page 85 in Feynman's "Photon-Hadron Interactions" equation 15.2 reads:

$$\tag1\vert \omega\rangle = \vert \omega_0\rangle+\frac{\delta}{m_\omega-m_\rho-\frac{\mathrm{i}\Gamma_\omega-\mathrm{i}\Gamma_\rho}{2}}\vert \rho_0\rangle$$
where $\vert\delta\vert\approx 3.7$ MeV (see p. 86 same book).

My question is where I can find an analogous expansion for the proton (say), i.e. something like

$$\tag2\vert p\rangle = c_0\vert p_0\rangle+c_1\vert h\rangle+\cdots$$
where $h=$ some hadron.